# Python 3. Никак не пойму в чем ошибка состоит

Tags: python, pygame

```
   class Engine(object):

def __init__(self, scene_map):
    self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

    while current_scene != last_scene:    <вот тут собственно ошибка
```

ошибка - line 19, in **init**
while current_scene != last_scene:

Answer (score 2):

```
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Это происходит из за:

```
 def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')
    while current_scene != last_scene:
```

Нужно:

```
 def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')
        while current_scene != last_scene:
```

Или:

```
def play(self):
    current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
    last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')
    return current_scene, last_scene 
last_scene, last_scene = self.play()
while current_scene != last_scene:
```

Comment: Соблюдайте отступы. 
У вас current_scene  и last_scene не определены из за того что вы вышли за границы функции